# Can't register C++ type to QML system

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5, qt-quick

I'm trying to add C++ type to QML system.

```
#include <QtGui/QGuiApplication>
#include <QDeclarativeEngine>
#include <QDeclarativeComponent>
#include "qtquick2applicationviewer.h"
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

class FooBar: public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine("qml/RBot/main.qml");

    qmlRegisterType<FooBar>("io.secorp", 1, 0, "FooBar");

    return app.exec();
}
```

But when I'm trying compile this(i don't import this in .qml file, only testing) I'm geting errors about debugging.

[image]

What's wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: The title of this question reads Qt 4, but the question is tagged with both qt4 and qt5, and your screenshot from Qt Creator indicates that you're compiling against Qt 5.1. My answer below addresses the case for Qt 5.

Answer (score 4):

You're mixing Qt Quick 1 and 2, which is unsupported. The QDeclarative headers are for Quick 1 and the QQml headers are for Quick 2.

Your includes should be:

```
#include <QtGui/QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlComponent>
#include "qtquick2applicationviewer.h"
#include "foobar.h"
```

The definition of FooBar should be in its own header, and QObject should be included there for moc to work its magic.

For more details, see this already reported bug in Qt:

[QTBUG-32138 - Hello World for QtQuick2 does not compile with #include  when QML debugging is on](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-32138)